# Drupal version Tag in Related Sections

Tags: feature-request

In *Questions that may already have your answer*, and *Related* sections, if question is tagged with drupal version I think it would be nice to see version tag next to a question.

*Related* questions are sometimes for different drupal version, so not really related sometimes.